# How to read in multi line excel cells into R

Tags: r, shiny, read.csv, xlconnect, r-xlsx

I am trying to read in an excel file into R. The data is formatted as follows:
[image]

As you can see, there are cells with multi line information. I am taking this excel file and putting it up on R shiny as a question. (As radio buttons)
Now if I read it using **read.xlsx**, my lines are squished together into one single line. 
How do I read the file into R with the multi line formatting preserved?
If I have a single line as my question, it is difficult to read and understand.

Answer (score 5):

While it may look like R has missed the line breaks, it hasn't, they're still there. R notates them as \n, or in the case of the example you give (where the person entering those sentences has pressed enter twice, R would have \n\n)

Try writing the data with:

```
write.xlsx(yourdata, "test.xlsx", sheetName="sheet1", row.names=FALSE)
```

The line breaks will be there!

Extra note: there are additional things to be wary of. For example, when you write an excel file, the default row height is the excel default of 14.5 (so you'll only see the first line of text - remember to increase the size to see more text). You could also set the row height when writing the excel file

Comment: Additionally, I think if you display the contents of the cell using the `cat()` rather than `print()` function, the `\n`s will be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys. So I read the file using `read.xlsx`, kept `allowEscapes = T` and then tried to display them on the shiny app. Shiny was not printing out the line breaks. 
I wanted the app to display the questions with line breaks.

Comment: @SwastikMohapatra I wonder if you can gsub the line breaks for some html, like swapping all “\n” for “</br>” (the html equivalent) ? Might be worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

Are you are using formula in cell? if yes then you need to open and close the file in excel to complete the calculations. if you are using windows then you can write a vbs script for that, as well.